# как установить библиотеку pyautogui в python при ошибке

Tags: python, pyautogui

При запуске программы:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ярослав/PycharmProjects/управление компьютером/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui as pg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

При установке:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyautogui in 
Requirement already satisfied: pymsgbox in 
Requirement already satisfied: PyTweening>=1.0.1 in 
Requirement already satisfied: pyscreeze>=0.1.21 in 
Requirement already satisfied: pygetwindow>=0.0.5 in 
Requirement already satisfied: mouseinfo in 
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=6.2.1 in 
Requirement already satisfied: pyrect in
Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in
```

Comment: Виртуальное окружение используете? Может, не в ту версию установили?

Comment: Я устанавливал  в терминале в pycharm версия питона 3ю8ю2

Answer (score 0):

Т.к информации мало, могу только предположить, что пакет установлен не для той версии python. Например скрипт запускает python3.8 а пакет установлен для python3.7

С [офф сайта](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=b92f88c6e17ef0dd3e28507b8191258e6a2993ee-1588693066-0-AXBBbx2tUpUi0xTVWD7ace_G9KMDtYN2aKheoFGJpVLnAj_mWDt1oBCOVOG5T5JW_UbQFuXKlaS5pVjlzcU3Ai3zps3MFtOfY_xExTvf3WTG8nPY9gCBl89eYD43m39TzNZYySwXaJ9x3bc6Pn6U02KRyXveIik3bDIxB5x1B2Ee9x41B43if5vZLvo1QI7jQQ_eFYey5mjEFZpdR822N2_7wI7LfPBfvNDKxe-92NDD6u7VlYdW5gQ_hvcU01NcuKSmc8jPKdC1OJ_N_AEVVNUGvQKXNlfIpsp-5D2BMcEN2E2uik0TBKCIja6Vj21ZyvYdNMuoPkzcN7KFmc3bEbf3DJTxO1fOv9d2EkdZDdFaVWxaTptAruxsgz8fF_Z_Helk2aavaPzPSU5to8h53AMZMNuIc8eySRkEi2QblXzIJBNrfM-pI6YV7Zxqr8DQivjq3GETVmtKOreHAcilZqCSZCX4MO4arp3-pc0jbFqB2Cz2d6W21PLtnPXc9cwrjHsgiIlnjnYx_o90X-FR0LCtlvfWl_8or2GIztsHUGN7) для установки в слуаее нескольких версий python нужно писать:

`py -3.8 -m pip install pyautogui` или `py -3.8 -m pip3 install pyautogui`

Comment: Спасибо, но с первым вариантом пишет тоже самое, а со вторым пишет, что нет такого pip3

Comment: попробуй поискать версии питона на своём ПК и запусти их в cmd. И по импортируй туда pyautogui. У меня просто была похожая проблема, но может у тебя другой случай. И попробуй установить pip3 и скачать через него, это часто решало мои проблемы.